# Mandatory and Optional Attributes in Schematron

Tags: xml, xpath, schematron

I need to specify a rule in Schematron where I say that every element `<xpto>` must have attributes `x` and `y` and all the other attributes it eventually has must be `z` or `w`.

So let's say I have the following element:

```
<xpto a="abc">
```

This is a wrong element because, not only does it does it not have the attributes `x` and `y`, it also has attribute `a` which is not one of the valid ones `(x,y,z,w)`.

A valid element would be:

```
<xpto x="abc" y="cba">
```

or

```
<xpto x="abc" y="cba" w="dsa">
```

I know how to specify mandatory attributes with the @attribute command, I just don't know how to specify that all attributes' name must be in some set, like `('x','y','z','w')` in the example given...

Answer (score 0):

```
<sch:pattern>
   <sch:rule context="xpto">
      <sch:assert test="every $attr in @* satisfies $attr/name()=('x','y','z','w')">Error message</sch:assert>
   </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```

Comment: every $x in ./attribute::*/name() satisfies $x=('x','y','z','w')

This worked for me. But thank you very much :)

Comment: @Daniel The `every` operator is what I couldn't remember, see my updated answer.